# Best Dictionary for Indian English

Tags: dictionaries, subcontinental-english

English (India) has evolved over the years. It's being given a separate place of its own since the no. of English-speakers are growing rapidly. An example would be the addition of the option English (India) in many popular websites and softwares.

What dictionary would be the most reliable standard for English (India)?

Comment: Are you familiar with Hobson Jobson?

Comment: @BarrieEnglad, +1 for Hobson Jobson.1. Searchable version of Hobson Jobson [http://dsal.uchicago.edu/dictionaries/hobsonjobson/] 2.Digital edition of Hobson Jobson [http://archive.org/stream/hobsonjobsonbein00yuleuoft#page/n7/mode/2up]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Websites for Indian English Dictionaries:

1. [www.VSubhash.IN](http://www.vsubhash.in/dictionary-of-indian-english.html)
2. [Amritt.com](https://amritt.com/india-english-dictionary/): "Helping Business People to Communicate with India"

Comment: Both of these seem to exclude those words that Indian English shares with other Englishes such as British or American.